# Only One Media Query Working. Can anyone advise on how the other one can work?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a simple web page with two CSS media queries. As I resize the browser, the first media query fires but I can't get the other one to work. The order seems to be appropriate, so does my syntax. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>McCann Echo Torre Lazur</title>
<style>

/**********************************************************************************
 * Structure
 **********************************************************************************/

body: {


}

#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    min-height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 2px;


}

#logo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.bioinfo {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 315px;
}

ul {
}

/**********************************************************************************
 * Media Queries
 **********************************************************************************/


 /* Screens with resolution less than 1024px width */
 @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .bioinfo {
        width: 49%;
        border-color:#ff0000;
    }
    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
    }
 } //end media screen

/* Screens with resolution less than 480px width */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .bioinfo {
        width: 95%;
        border-color:#ffffff;
    }
    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
    }
} 



</style>


</head>
<body>
<div id='wrapper'>
<header>
    <div id='logo'>Logo Here</div>
</header>

    <div id='bios'>
        <div class='bioinfo'>Bio 1</div>
        <div class='bioinfo'>Bio 2</div>
        <div class='bioinfo'>Bio 3</div>
        <div class='bioinfo'>Bio 4</div>
        <div class='bioinfo'>Bio 5</div>
        <div class='bioinfo'>Bio 6</div>
    </div>



<div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a discrepancy between your (code) comments and the values in your media queries. (480 vs. 700) Is that the issue? If not, have you tried putting the 2nd media query block in front of the first?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not concerned about the pixels in the comments. When I resize the browser (Chrome or Safari), the 1024px @media screen fires, the other one does not. I've switched the order, and only the 1024px one works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//end media screen` is not a valid comment. Remove it and this works.

CSS comments use the `/* */` syntax.

Comment: If this answers your question, mark it as such with the checkmark next to the answer. You ought to do this for all your questions, I'm only saying this because Oded seems to have answered your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710479/how-do-i-establish-a-sql-query-for-this-many-to-many-table) and you haven't marked it as such yet. Marking questions answered is a part of being a good citizen of Stackoverflow!

Comment: Okay, I will do that. Sorry, I'm new to the Stackoverflow.